# What is wrong with this Bash script menu?

Tags: bash

I'm tired of typing in long commands to do simple things so I've written this  short Bash menu script to speed things up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PS3="Nginx? "
options=("start", "stop", "status", "exit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "start")
            sudo service nginx start
            ;;
        "stop")
            sudo service nginx stop
            ;;
        "status")
            sudo service nginx status
            ;;
        "exit")
            echo "Exiting"
            exit 1
            ;;
          *) echo "Invalid selection";;
     esac
done
```

It's displaying the menu correctly:

```
1) start
2) stop
3) status
4) exit
```

But only option 4, exit, works correctly.  When I hit 1, 2, or 3, I get "Invalid selection".  Am I entering the sudo commands incorrectly?  Thank you.

Comment: BTW, it's more typical to just run `yourscript start`, or `yourscript start`, &c. -- reading the operation to perform off the command line, rather than from stdin. This would make your code easier to use from a script, and mean it could be implemented with only this one line (after the shebang): `sudo service nginx "$@"`.

Comment: "Use spaces, not commas, to separate array elements." -- [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) when run on your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual menu displayed by this code is not what you gave in the question, but instead:

```
1) start,
2) stop,
3) status,
4) exit
```

This difference -- commas on the end of the first three items -- is instructive.

---

This is an array-syntax declaration issue. Take out the commas:

```
options=( "start" "stop" "status" "exit" )
```

...by the way, since your contents are all single-word literals with no glob characters, the quotes don't do anything; it would be just as correct to write:

```
options=( start stop status exit )
```

The original code accepts not `start` but `start,`; not `stop`, but `stop,`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see that.